# Are deep link parameters preserved in intents when users install the app via deep link?

Tags: android, deep-linking, google-app-invites

I would like to use Google's app-invites engine with deep links.
I can attach a deep link to the invitation but does that work in case where user installed the app from the link? Do they still get the intent with the deep link parameters?

Comment: Usually, those links go to your own website, it then stores the IP address,params, etc.. and redirect to the apk download, when the apk is installed, it will go again to the website and there you have the link and the apk relationed.

Comment: In what phase does it go to the link?

Comment: The first one, those links go to your own website, they store data and redirect you to the playstore.